# PHP link text between <br>

Tags: php, string

I don't want to be a help vampire, I'm just asking for a general direction or which technologies would have to be used to make this possible.

I have an a string, something like this:

```
joke<br>kid<br>forreal<br>me
```

How would I turn it into something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/chat/user.php?q=joke">joke</a><br>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/chat/user.php?q=kid">kid</a><br>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/chat/user.php?q=forreal">forreal</a><br>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/chat/user.php?q=me">me</a><br>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and then we can nudge you along

Comment: For searching and replacing text, [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex) is what you want to use

Comment: I have no idea about what to try, I am trying to be pointed to the right direction. I didn't ask for the code necessarily, `I'm just asking for a general direction or which technologies would have to be used to make this possible.`

Comment: use jquery `wrap()` method

Comment: @AkramElHamdaoui this is PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: @AkramElHamdaoui I was asking for PHP, not jQuery, but it seems that this may just work in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = "...";

// split the string on every "<br>"
$users = explode("<br>", $string);

// loop through the users, adding the anchor
for ($i = 0, $count = count($users); $i < $count; $i++)
{
    echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/chat/user.php?q=' . $users[$i] . '">'  . $users[$i] . '</a>';

    // add "<br>" to every user except the last
    if ($i < ($count - 1))
        echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying this, with arrays and explode, but the problem is that it end with an extra '<br>', which wasn't there in the original string when it outputs.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely works for me. :)

Comment: @user2049022 First and last time I ever try to answer something without testing it first. *SHOULD FINALLY BE GOOD*.

Comment: I noticed the problem was that the `"` and the `"` were contradicting, so I fixed that. :)

Comment: @Supericy Thanks for editing your answer, and your answer was really helpful for me. :) So `for` is a complex loop, and `foreach` and is a basic one for `arrays`, right? :)

Comment: @Supericy why you don't use implode to avoid all of this complexity

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by separating the string by the `<br>` and you can achieve this by using [PHP Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Which will give you an array and you need to loop through it and generate the html text as you needed

It will be much better if you tried to write the code then we will all help much more :)

If you were unable to write maybe we can help

**Code Edit**

```
$string = "joke<br>kid<br>forreal<br>me";

$tags = explode("<br>", $string);

$new = array(); 

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    $new[] = '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/chat/user.php?q=' . $tag . '">'  . $tag . '</a>';

}

echo implode("<br>", $new);
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying this, with arrays and explode, but the problem is that it end with an extra '<br>', which wasn't there in the original string when it outputs

Comment: I don't understand you 100% can you give me an example ?

Comment: Use `implode()` to put the string back together with '<br>' between them, and you won't get an extra one.

Comment: @barmar How would this work??? I'd first have the original string, and then I'd explode it right? So it would be an array, and then I would `foreach` and add links, right, each one seperated by a `<br>`. Then, I'd end up with another `<br>`. I don't see how implode could be used to work this out.

Comment: @user2049022 if you put each HTML string for each key in array and then you passed th array to implode and added the <br> you will end up without the last <br>

Comment: Could you edit your answer to provide a demo? Or comment a codeviper here?

Comment: @user2049022 check it now

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a couple of built in DOM parsers: [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`SimpleXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  In my experience, the latter is better for reading and simple manipulation whereas the former is great for more complex manipulation.

It seems like you want to use `DOMDocument` to find the text nodes in your string and wrap or replace them with the respective anchors.

[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) may be an option to, but it's not native to PHP.

Comment: But this is not actually a string parsing